# How to use Folding Expression to initialize an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, variadic-templates, fold-expression

I come across with a weird problem in which MSVC doesn't let me to use fold expression to initialize an array in the following:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t ...dims>
class Matrix {
public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << (... + dims) << '\n';
    }
    
    T matrix[(... + dims)];      // <-- error C2059: syntax error: '...'
};

int main()
{
    Matrix<int, 3, 3, 3> m;
    m.print();
    Matrix<int, 3, 2, 1> n;
    n.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the errors:

> (10): error C2059: syntax error: '...' (11): note: see
> reference to class template instantiation 'Matrix' being
> compiled (10): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

I tried GCC and everything just worked perfectly fine!

Is there any workaround to use fold expression directly to initialize an array with MSVC?

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: Works [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xjOhQ7isOncjPSSg) with GCC and C++17.

Comment: I retracted my comment. I didn't realise the error was on the _third_ use of `...` - if it really was an issue of the compiler not recognizing the syntax it would have complained about the 2 preceding instances lines first. I tried it on godbolt with VC19.30 with `/std:c++20` and the error reproduces there too.

Comment: @Evg This one works but I prefer not to use dummy variable while I can use fold expression directly!

Comment: @NimaGhorab Then you may need to change compiler. It looks like a bug in MSVC. Both `g++` and `clang++` compiles it fine. Have you tried it in VS2022 beta?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes I tried it with the latest version of MSVC but errors are still there.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a bug in the MS compiler. As with any bug of such kind, it's hard to tell what exactly goes wrong unless you know MS compiler internals.

A workaround is the introduction of an intermediate member variable:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t... dims>
class Matrix {
    // ...
    static constexpr std::size_t my_size = (... + dims);
    T matrix[my_size];
};
```

or a static member function:

```
    static constexpr std::size_t my_size() { return (... + dims); }
    T matrix[my_size()];
```

Comment: Not to mention that doing so we can reuse the same `my_size()` in `print`, easily test it somehow and if, later, we decide that a `*` would be more appropriate than a `+`, change it in just one place.

Comment: @Bob__ Good point, too. Thanks.

Comment: @Evg Thank you for the answer I submit this in Developer Community of Microsoft. I hope they fix this bug as soon as possible!